# Creating dictionary with scraped values (Beautiful Soup Python)

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I'm trying to create a dictionary from two arrays of scraped data. Everything in this code works except for the last step, where it throws the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
>        19 tale_data_governors = [data.string for data in table_data_governors]
>        20 
>   ---> 21 dictionary = dict(zip(table_data_governors,table_data))
>
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

```
#Return the results in dictionary form 
#{'Brown': 56.0126582278481, 'Whitman': 43.9873417721519}

html = requests.get("https://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/ca/california_governor_whitman_vs_brown-1113.html").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

#Scrape the percentage Numbers
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
table_row = table.find_all('tr')[1]
table_data = table_row.find_all('td')[3:5]

#Scrape the Names
table_row_governors = table.find_all('tr')[0]
table_data_governors = table_row_governors.find_all('th')[3:5]
table_data_governors

table_data = [data.string for data in table_data]
tale_data_governors = [data.string for data in table_data_governors]

dictionary = dict(zip(table_data_governors,table_data))
```

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks

**EDIT:** I think it may have something to do with this:

```
[(<th>Brown (D)</th>, u'53.1'), (<th>Whitman (R)</th>, u'41.7')]
```

This is the array of tuples I get when I call zip(). I'm not quite sure why this happens. I thought that data.string would convert these into strings..

**EDIT 2: This code works**

```
a = zip(table_data, table_data_governors)

b = {}
for x,y in a:
    b[y] = x

b
```

Strange stuff. Might have something to do with the Ipython notebook.

Comment: Could you provide the whole error message?

Comment: yep just edited

Comment: I ran your code in python 2 and 3 without receiving this error...is the code you posted identical to what you were running?  Also which version of requests and beautiful soup are you using?

Comment: Yep code is exactly the same. How do I find the versions in ipython notebook

Comment: Strange, and the last line is the one throwing the error? Also, do you use pip to install libraries?

Comment: string is unicode so i guess it is python 3

Comment: yeah i use pip to install libraries

Comment: There might be a typo in your code. `tale_data_governors` is being defined and `table_data_governors` is being called later. That should fix the problem.

Comment: You can use the command `pip freeze` to see what you have currently installed.

Comment: @AnirudhSridhar This seems like a problem.  I fixed it here and still am not able to repeat the error OP is receiving.

Comment: @FarmerJoe Yes, the OP should not be getting a TypeError here. I am checking what could be the possible solution.

Comment: @bugsyb You might have to help us a little more here as I am not able to reproduce your error.  Is there any more to this code that has been omitted?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code.

You have defined `tale_data_governors` and are calling `table_data_governors` later.